# Merge dataframes of different sizes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames `d1` and `d2` respectively as:

```
x   y  z
10  10 7
10  12 6
11  10 8
11  12 2
12  10 1
12  12 5

x  y  z
10 10 100
11 10 200
12 12 400
```

I want something like:

```
x   y  z
10  10 100
10  12 6
11  10 200
11  12 2
12  10 1
12  12 400
```

I am really sorry for the trivial question, I could not get the answer.

Comment: just remove the first, third, and last rows of d1 and rbind(d1, d2)

Comment: Could you elaborate what happened with 10,10,7? Do first two columns make a "key" and third one is a "value"?

Comment: Dear MLavoie, It is just an example. The real data is bigger.

Comment: Dear mlt, x and y are kind of longitude and latitude and z is value

Comment: I mean can it be multivalued for a given x&y? And consider [dput and this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: No, z is single as given in example.

Comment: One approach (not most efficient) is to have a list with "x;y" (converted to charater and separated by semicolon) as a key and use [modifyList](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/modifyList.html).

Comment: Dear mlt, please provide a reproducible example. It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your description I understand that you want to replace the `z` values in `d1` with the `z` values in `d2` when `x` & `y` match.

Using base R:

```
d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by = c("x","y"), all.x = TRUE)
d3[is.na(d3$z.y),"z.y"] <- d3[is.na(d3$z.y),"z.x"]
d3 <- d3[,-3]
names(d3)[3] <- "z"
```

which gives:

```
> d3
   x  y   z
1 10 10 100
2 10 12   6
3 11 10 200
4 11 12   2
5 12 10   1
6 12 12 400
```

---

Using the *data.table*-package:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d1) # convert the data.frame to a data.table
setDT(d2) # idem

# join the two data.table's and replace the values
d1[d2, on = .(x, y), z := i.z]
```

or in one go:

```
setDT(d1)[setDT(d2), on = .(x, y), z := i.z]
```

which gives:

```
> d1
    x  y   z
1: 10 10 100
2: 10 12   6
3: 11 10 200
4: 11 12   2
5: 12 10   1
6: 12 12 400
```

---

Using the *dplyr* package:

```
d3 <- left_join(d1, d2, by = c("x","y")) %>%
  mutate(z.y = ifelse(is.na(z.y), z.x, z.y)) %>%
  select(-z.x) %>%
  rename(z = z.y)
```

Since [release 0.5.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.5.0) you can also use the `coalesce`-function for this (thx to Laurent Hostert for [bringing it to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438349/merge-dataframes-of-different-sizes/34438586?noredirect=1#comment108698063_34438586)):

```
d3 <- left_join(d1, d2, by = c("x","y")) %>% 
  mutate(z = coalesce(z.y, z.x)) %>% 
  select(-c(z.x, z.y))
```

Comment: @Pankaj thanx; I added also a `dplyr` alternative

Comment: @Jaap I've added my answer expanding your example, see below

Comment: @Jaap In dplyr release v0.5.0 (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.5.0) the `coalesce` function was added. This can simplify your dplyr solution:  
`d3 <- left_join(d1, d2, by = c("x","y")) %>%
  mutate(z = coalesce(z.y, z.x)) %>%
  select(-c(z.x, z.y))`

Comment: @LaurenHostert Thx for notifying! I've included it in my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

On top of excellent [@Jaap answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438586/3526832) wrt data.table

In data.table, you could join using keys, and with data.table anything done via using keys is the fastest option around. You could even have different column names, see modified example below.

Along the lines, data:

```
x  y  z
10 10 100
11 10 200
12 12 400

x  q  z
10  10 7
10  12 6
11  10 8
11  12 2
12  10 1
12  12 5
```

and code:

```
library(data.table)

d1 <- fread("d1.csv", sep=" ")
d2 <- fread("d2.csv", sep=" ")

# here is data.table keys magic
# note different column names
setkey(d1, x, q)
setkey(d2, x, y)

q <- d2[d1][is.na(z), z := i.z][, i.z := NULL]

print(q)
```

result:

```
    x  y   z
1: 10 10 100
2: 10 12   6
3: 11 10 200
4: 11 12   2
5: 12 10   1
6: 12 12 400
```

Comment: Dear Severin Pappadeux, thanks for improving suggestions.

Comment: You can also join with different column names when using `on`: `d2[d1, on=c("x"="x","y"="q")]`. With the [development version of `data.table` (1.9.7)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) you can shorten this to `d2[d1, on=c("x","y"="q")]`. Not sure about whether setting keys is faster than using `on`. Did you test it?

Comment: Nice, but this returns an entirely new data.table first and then updates that -- all just to add a column (= memory inefficient). See Jaap's updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to ensure that there is only one `z` value for each `x` and `y` value.  The main question is how you choose which z value to associate with it.  From the description, I'm guessing you either want the second data frame to always override, or you want the maximum value to be taken.

Start with the raw data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), y = c(10L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 12L), z = c(7L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2 <- structure(list(x = 10:12, y = c(10L, 10L, 12L), z = c(100L, 200L,400L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

If it's the max you want, then you probably want to simply combine the two frames, and then extract the max for each `x` and `y`:

```
merged.df <- aggregate(z ~ x + y, data = rbind(df1, df2), max)
```

If, instead, you want the second data frame to override the first, then you would aggregate using the last value to match

```
merged.df <- aggregate(z ~ x+ y, data=rbind(df1, df2), function(d) tail(d, n=1))
```

If you have many columns besides `z`, then I can only assume that you want the latter behavior.  For this, you're better off using a library like `data.table` or `dplyr`.  In `dplyr`, it would look like this

```
require(dplyr)
merged.df <- rbind(df1, df2) %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise_each(funs(last))
```

With `data.table` it would look like

```
require(data.table)
merged.df <- setDT(rbind(df1, df2))[, lapply(.SD, last), .(x,y)]
```

Comment: Dear user295691, Thanks a lot for sharing useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to use `merge` this *update-join* can be done in *base* by using `match` and `which` to find the indexes used for sub-setting the tables and `interaction` to make one key vector out of two.

With this way, neither the *order* nor the *size* of `d1` will be changed. In case a *key* in `d2` is represented twice, the first occurrence will be used to update `d1`.

```
d1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="x   y  z
10  10 7
10  12 6
11  10 8
11  12 2
12  10 1
12  12 5")
d2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="x  y  z
10 10 100
11 10 200
12 12 400")

key <- c("x", "y") #define which columns are used as matching key
idx <- match(interaction(d2[key]), interaction(d1[key])) #find where it matches
d1$z[idx] <- d2$z #make the update

d1 #show result
#   x  y   z
#1 10 10 100
#2 10 12   6
#3 11 10 200
#4 11 12   2
#5 12 10   1
#6 12 12 400
```

Alternative you can check if there was a match between d1 and d2 like:

```
idx <- match(interaction(d1[key]), interaction(d2[key]))
idxn <- which(!is.na(idx)) #find where it does not match
d1$z[idxn] <- d2$z[idx[idxn]]
```

or

```
idx <- match(interaction(d2[key]), interaction(d1[key]))
idxn <- which(!is.na(idx))
d1$z[idx[idxn]] <- d2$z[idxn]
```