# Filling table column by matching several rows from different tables with data.table

Tags: r, loops, vector, data.table, matching

I need help finding a solution to the following problem:

Here is an example data set:

```
library(data.table)
x_coord <- rep(sort(rep(c(1:3),3)),2)
y_coord <- rep(c(1:3),6)
time_info <- c(rep(strptime("201701010000", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M"),9), rep(strptime("201701010005", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M"),9))

table1 <- data.table(x = x_coord, y = y_coord, time = time_info)

table2 <- data.table(x = c(1,1,3,2), y = c(1,1,3,1),time = rep(time_info[1], 4), values = c(3,5,8,6))
# table2 has one unique time-value
```

The aim is to fill in table1 with the values from table2 so that it looks like this:

```
table3 <- table1
for (i in c(1:nrow(table2))) {
table3[x == table2$x[i] & y == table2$y[i] & time == table2$time[i],"values" := .(table2$values[i])]
}
```

There are several constraints:

1. table1 does not contain all coordinates from table2 and the reverse. Each coordinates/time combination has only one corresponding value so there is no issue with multiple values per coordinate/time.
2. I can't do it manually, since "table1" has in reality 2*10^7 rows and I want to get the values from almost 100'000 "table2"s which each have the size of about 10000 rows and which come from a different file each.

I've tried merging but then when it's Looping, it adds a new "values"-column at each Iteration (and on top of that it's taking really long). I've also tried matching with

```
table1[time == table2$time[1] & paste0(x,y) %in% paste0(table2$x,table2$y), "values" := .(table2$values)]
```

but then I am not sure that the right value is assigned to the right coordinate.

I hope my question is clear, sorry if not! Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [*How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/2204410)

Comment: Also relevant: [*Merge dataframes of different sizes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438349/2204410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join with `data.table`:

```
table1[table2, on = .(x, y, time), values := values][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     x y                time values
>  1: 1 1 2017-01-01 01:00:00      5
>  2: 1 2 2017-01-01 01:00:00     NA
>  3: 1 3 2017-01-01 01:00:00     NA
>  4: 2 1 2017-01-01 01:00:00      6
>  5: 2 2 2017-01-01 01:00:00     NA
>  6: 2 3 2017-01-01 01:00:00     NA
>  7: 3 1 2017-01-01 01:00:00     NA
>  8: 3 2 2017-01-01 01:00:00     NA
>  9: 3 3 2017-01-01 01:00:00      8
> 10: 1 1 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 11: 1 2 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 12: 1 3 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 13: 2 1 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 14: 2 2 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 15: 2 3 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 16: 3 1 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 17: 3 2 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> 18: 3 3 2017-01-01 01:05:00     NA
> ```

Comment: just one thing: the values were not updating once it went through the loop; so I found through the link that was given above that one has to update with
    value := i.value

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to use the dplyr package you could do this.

```
library(dplyr)
table3 = table1 %>% left_join(table2)
```